# How to get JSONObject for RealmObject

Tags: android, json, realm

Im using retrofit2 to get data. And putting it into Realm.
But i dont know how to get jsonobject from jsonobject and put it into RealmObject. What should i write in my RealmObject model? I new in Realm DB. Thanx a lot!

JSONObject:

```
{
        "birth_date": "Fri, 12 Jul 1968 00:00:00 GMT",
        "gender": {
            "id": "male",
            "name": "Мужской"
        },
        "group": 1
    }
```

Model

```
public class PatientEntity extends RealmObject{

@SerializedName("gender") private RealmList<Gender> gender;

@SerializedName("birth_date")
String birth_date;

@SerializedName("group")
String group;

public String getBirth_date() {
    return birth_date;
}

public void setBirth_date(String birth_date) {
    this.birth_date = birth_date;
}

public RealmList<Gender> getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(RealmList<Gender> gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public String getGroup() {
    return group;
}

public void setGroup(String group) {
    this.group = group;
}}
```

Gender model class

```
public class Gender extends RealmObject{
@SerializedName("id")
String id;

@SerializedName("name")
String name;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902904/how-can-i-serialize-a-realmobject-to-json-in-realm-for-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038147/realmgsonretrofit2-parsing basically the answer is using a type adapter

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor to your realm object(`PatientEntity.java`) like this

```
public PatientEntity(){
}

public PatientEntity (String birth_date,String group){
this.birth_date=birth_date;
this.group=group;
}
```

Once you have the parsed data from retrofit saved as strings suppose `birth` and `group` , pass it to the constructor like

```
PatientEntity patient=new PatientEntity (birth,group);
```

and add it to realm like this

```
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.copyToRealm(patient);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Note : you will need to initialize real in oncreate to access `realm`

*****EDIT****

```
RequestInterface request = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
    Call<PatientEntity> call1=request.getPOJO();
    call1.enqueue(new Callback<PatientEntity>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PatientEntity> call, Response<PatientEntity> response) {

            PatientEntity patient=response.body(); //get PatientEntity 
            Gender gender=response.body().getGender();  //get Gender

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<PatientEntity > call, Throwable t) {                

    });
```

Comment: Ok. But, what about "gender" jsonobject? The issue is about "gender". Should i use RealmList or what? =) Thanx

Comment: have you created "gender" model class, if so share it